# http not found issue when url have % symbol

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

It showing lot of urls as 404 not found. Of course there is badly formed querystring in the url.

```
http://www.example.com/ref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.org/
```

Bbove url is failing to reach `.htaccess` verification.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request_url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If that url reach/passthrough the above `.htaccess` rule, I can simply add `R=301`, but that url does not reach/passingthrough that `.htaccess` rule and shows 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

it wont work because the urls are encoded and will be decoded as (`%2F` for / and `%5C` for `\`) respectively.
Apache has Security limitations for these kind of requests 
check these Urls for more info

https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2007-0450

[http://securitytracker.com/id/1018110 (Look at section 4. Solution)](http://securitytracker.com/id/1018110)

To make it work either pass decoded request or enable `AllowEncodedSlashes` in apache config and restart the apache service

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes